# Similar Ruby solution to JavaScript's spread operator?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a structure in my controllers that gets repetitive. I'm defining the minimum required params and maximum permitted params as follows:

```rb
MIN_KEYS = %i[email password password_confirmation role].freeze
MAX_KEYS = %i[email password password_confirmation role company_admin company_id].freeze
```

Is there a clean way to say "everything inside MIN_KEYS, and then some"? In a Javascript approach I'd just do the following:

```rb
MIN_KEYS = %i[email password password_confirmation role].freeze
MAX_KEYS = %i[...MIN_KEYS company_admin company_id].freeze
```

...this obviously doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to what you're after using a splat but it doesn't combine with the `%i[...]` array constructor without a bit of chicanery:

```
MAX_KEYS = [*MIN_KEYS, *%i[company_admin company_id]].freeze
MAX_KEYS = [*MIN_KEYS, :company_admin, :company_id].freeze
```

Or you could add arrays:

```
MAX_KEYS = (MIN_KEYS + %i[company_admin company_id]).freeze
```

and not bother with splat/spread at all.